# No such module in 'Alamofire' Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire Pod but it gives error like this;

[projectScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0jOx.png)

Answer (score 0):

try cmd+b on keyboard and retry